# Displaying and editing sound in wave, python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, audio, wav

I am trying to do the following using the module wave *(and not another)* in python 2.7:

- display the spectrum of a wav file
- add silences to a wav file at the beginning/end

Wave's documentation is rather shallow.

So far I have tried :

```
def display(filename):
    file=wave.open(filename,'r')
    freq=file._framerate
    n=file._nframes
    Y=file.readframes(n)
    plt.close()
    plt.plot(Y)
    plt.show()
    file.close()
```

but it would seem that file.readframes returns binary data, and I don't know how to use that.

For the part where I add silence, I have found some tutorials on how to *create* sound using wave, but I also need to *replicate* the old sound as follows :

```
def addSilence(filename,length);
    fileR=wave.open(filename,'r')
    fileW=wave.open('_'+filename,'w')

    # add silence here to fileW

    for i in fileR.readframes(fileR._nframes):
        #copy frames from fileR to fileW

    fileR.close()
    fileW.close()
```

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

its best to ask separate questions here on SO ...

WAV format normally has a 44 byte header prior to the actual PCM audio binary data so keep this in mind on your read/write ...

silence is typically a value zero where the normalized audio varies from -1 to +1 ... depending on the flavor of WAV you are reading in (your header values will tell you this) your bit depth typically is 16 bit (2^16 possible values from 0 to 2^16 ... or negative 2^15 to positive (2^15 - 1))

you say Display the spectrum ... this can be in time domain (amplitude across time) so simply map the audio curve onto a plot *OR* frequency domain (height of the curve represents energy across frequencies) where you will need to first pass the data through a Fourier transform